# Error in serializing classes with traits on Scala using pickling?

Tags: scala, class, serialization, pickle, traits

I am trying to serialize a Scala class using Pickling.

```
  import scala.pickling.Defaults._
  import scala.pickling.json._

  trait Tr[T<: Tr[T]]{}
  class Sub(z: Int) extends Tr[Sub] {}
  class Data(b: Tr[_])

  val message = new Data(new Sub(1)).pickle.value
```

I am getting this error on compilation:

> Error:..... type arguments [_$2] do not conform to trait Tr's type
>   parameter bounds [T <: Tr[T]]
>         val message = new Data(new Sub(1)).pickle.value

Comment: This works: `class Data[T<: Tr[T]](val b: Tr[T])`

Answer (score 1):

What about using the following class hierarchy:

```scala
trait Tr[T <: Tr[T]]
case class Sub(z: Int) extends Tr[Sub]
case class Data[T <: Tr[T]](b: T)

val message = Data(Sub(1)).pickle.value
```

that is pickled like:

```json
{
  "$type": "Data[Sub]",
  "b": {
    "z": 1
  }
}
```